# WooCommerce New Order email subject filters

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I see how woocommerce has a default new order subject line 
[{site_title}] New customer order ({order_number}) - {order_date}

How can I add the product name in the subject line of this email. is there a list of the available filters for the email subject lines? I'd like to be able to do this without having to write custom php. I'm looking to do something like this:

New Order - [{product_name}] ({order_number}) - {order_date}

Comment: Sorry but is not possible to have the product name in the email filters, because an order is made of one or multiple products (or items)… So the product name is not available in that filters.

Comment: You can filter the email subject, but as LoicTheAztec said an order may include multiple products so you'd either have to display them all or find some other way to control the output (ex: maybe only the first, etc)